# Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart, ios14

I have updated my phone's OS version to iOS 14 and spent today updating Xcode to version 12, yet when I try to build my Flutter app on my iPhone 11 - iOS 14 through Android Studio, it gives me this error:

```
Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version.
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-09-18 19:14:26.576 ios-deploy[30916:201883] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000022: The service is invalid. AMDeviceSecureStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), NULL, &con)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on 00008030-00012C200C45802E.
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on Azheen’s.
```

Comment: Is it iOS 14 beta? I think u can't run your apps to a beta version, because xcode does recognizes the system since it didn't got updated yet

Comment: how would i know if its beta?

Comment: i have upgraded my os version yesterday

Comment: My app runs properly from Xcode, but shows the above error when I use the command flutter run from terminal. Any idea why?

Answer (score 6):

This problem is somewhat confusing, I got the same error with Xcode 12.0.1 and iOS 14.2 beta.
This solved for me

Download Device support files of iOS 14.0 [from this link](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport).

for iOS 14.2 beta [there is a pull request that is not yet merged](https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport/pull/71)

1. Unzip and Paste it in this location. `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/`

[image: hierarchy]

2. ReOpen Xcode.

Comment: Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'Symbols'. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown!

Answer (score 5):

This is what I did:

1. Updated Xcode
2. `flutter clean` on the terminal.
3. `flutter upgrade` on the terminal.
4. Open Xcode and run the application once.
5. `flutter clean` again.
6. `flutter run`.

It should work now.

Comment: Flutter versions 1.2X has loads of problems with build servers, is there no way to fix this on ```1.17.5``` ?

Answer (score 4):

This [issued](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64045) was raised a while back in August in the flutter repo. Currently, the issue has been fixed by the recent flutter update.

Run `flutter upgrade` to v1.20.4 to get the fix

Comment: flutter is the latest version

Comment: the version released 4 days ago??

Comment: hmm, run `flutter clean` then try running the project again

Comment: admin@Admins-MacBook-Pro-3 ios %  flutter --version
Flutter 1.22.0-10.0.pre.252 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 78929661fb (4 hours ago) • 2020-09-18 08:08:30 -0700
Engine • revision 2abe69c608
Tools • Dart 2.10.0 (build 2.10.0-136.0.dev)

Comment: oh, you're in the master branch

Comment: try switching to the stable branch and building the app

Comment: I have same issue and i can't update my flutter version because I'm depending on not updated packages

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this problem recently, most likely it can be caused due to the reason, that your iOS Device is running a higher version than you `xcode` can support.

Example:

Apple release new iOS for iPhone i.e. 14.2 and you upgrade your device right away, than you ran into this issue, because the `xcode` may not have the latest version of your device support files, meaning xcode can only suuport iOS 14.1 or lower. Apple sometimes release newer iOS without providing update of xcode device support files.

There is 4 solutions for this:

1. Keep your iOS Device on the current stable version of xcode
2. Downgrade your current iOS device
3. Install device support files manually
4. Install xcode beta from Apple Developer https://developer.apple.com/download/

It is an annoying issue, Apple should not release any iOS without having the supporting tools released at the same time, or they should run a warning.

Comment: Thanks for your and @EdHuamani. Downloading the support files listed in EdHuamani comment and placing them on the respective directory solved it for me.  I really started getting annoyed with the whole flutter thing. I am spending most of my time fixing these issues rather than developing something useful.

Comment: Unable to locate DeviceSupport directory with suffix 'Symbols'. This probably means you don't have Xcode installed, you will need to launch the app manually and logging output will not be shown!

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this issue today on Visual Studio. It appeared that my Dart SDK version was too out of date and upgrading it appeared to fix the problem.

I did upgrade my Flutter version first, and then ran into a problem with the `vsync` property of `AnimationController` not being recognized, which was solved by upgrading the Dart SDK, so I'm not sure who the real culprit was (or if it was a combination of both).

Instructions on upgrading your Dart SDK: https://dart.dev/get-dart