# Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version in Flutter While Xcode Already Updated

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, dart

I know this Question already in stackoverflow at [63959415](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63959415/your-xcode-version-may-be-too-old-for-your-ios-version), But Not any solution is worked for me thats why i am asking this Question.

My Xcode version already updated
flutter already in latest version
dart sdk is also on latest version

my Xcode vserion is : **Xcode 12.1**
my flutter version is : **Flutter 1.24.0-7.0.pre.41**
dart SDK version is : **Dart SDK version: 2.12.0-3.0.dev (dev)**
real device : Iphone SE and Iphone 8

Here is My Error that i always got when i run my ios app to real device.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone in debug mode...
lib/main.dart:1
Automatically signing iOS for device deployment using specified development team in Xcode project: T84HU2TC76
Xcode build done.                                           31.1s
Installing and launching...
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Error launching app. Try launching from within Xcode via:
    open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Your Xcode version may be too old for your iOS version.
═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
2020-10-31 12:19:47.784 ios-deploy[45301:248878] [ !! ] Error 0xe8000022: The service is invalid. AMDeviceSecureStartService(device, CFSTR("com.apple.debugserver"), NULL, &con)
Could not run build/ios/iphoneos/Runner.app on e149fc3a454f1163a5b3eefacd188b64362cb5c1.
Exited (sigterm)
Try launching Xcode and selecting "Product > Run" to fix the problem:
  open ios/Runner.xcworkspace

Error launching application on iPhone.
```

anybody has working solution ???

Comment: I also have this issue...